# How to pass a client certificate to backend web server, while using iis as a forward proxy?

Tags: .net, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-6, iis-8

I need to forward the requets sent to the iis to another backend server which runs in https.

I created the forward proxy to send the request to backend server, but the backend server is failing as there is no ssl **client** certificate passed.

Could you let me know how to pass **client** ssl certificate to my backend server using iis forward proxy setup. I am using iis on windows 10.

HTTP request received by a site in iis server runs a web service on localhost, this web service is forwarded to backend server using forward proxy, but how to pass the certificate to this forward proxy to communicate with backend server.

I know how to use ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse and SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile in apache but how to do it in IIS server

Comment: You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: You have to elaborate further on. Are you trying to pass a **client** certificate?

Who passes a certificate to whom?

Comment: @Arie yes, I need to pass client certificate to backend server, certifificate should be there in that iis machine which have to be used while forwarding request to backend server using forward proxy